# Access Drupal webform fields in custom page

Tags: php, drupal-7

I've placed a copy of the webform-submission page in my sites theme folder, and am modifying it to display the submissions pages how I would like. At the moment, to print an elements value, I use:

```
$submission->data[n]['value'][0]
```

Where data[n] is specific to the element in the webform. Is there any way I can use something more like `$submission->data[element_key]['value'][0]` to get the field info. It just makes for much easier reading, especially since I won't be the person maintaining the site.

Thanks.

p.s. this is in Drupal 7, webform 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$usbmission` array is built in the function [`webform_get_submissions`](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/webform_get_submissions/7).

Notice that the table which contains the `element_key` data you're looking for (`webform_component` table) is not queried in this function.

So if you want that data, you would have to fetch the `element_key` information yourself and rebuild the `$submission` array in an implementation of `hook_webform_submission_load`.